# How to print n level (deep) nested dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

How can we print n level deep nested dictionary in c# using a recursive function or with some other method?
the dictionary is like

```
Dictionary<string,object> myDict;
```

the object could be a dictionary for n time.
I tried something like this

```
 foreach (string key in nestedDict.Keys)
            {

                object nextLevel = nestedDict[key];

                    if(nextLevel.GetType()== typeof(string))
                    {
                    foreach(var val in nestedDict)
                    {
                        Debug.Log($" the key is  {val.Key}");
                        Debug.Log($" the value is {val.Value}");
                        if(val.Value.GetType()== typeof(Dictionary<,>))
                        {
                            NestedDictIteration((Dictionary<string, object>)val.Value);

                        }

                    }
                    break;
                    }
                    else
                NestedDictIteration((Dictionary<string, object>)nextLevel);
            }
```

Regards
GM

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, please [edit] your question to include details of what you've tried already

Comment: First: Your idea with recursion is not bad. You only have to understand how recursion works (did you try already something?). And you have to understand, that the dictionary itself does not know which level it is. That´s your task in your recursive method.

Comment: I have added the partial function that i was trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple to write the recursive method, I have added a `level` argument just to show the tree a little easier:

```
static void NestedPrint(Dictionary<string,object> dict, int level = 0)
{
    foreach(var item in dict)
    {
        if(item.Value is Dictionary<string,object> nested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ',level)}{item.Key}:");
            NestedPrint(nested,level+1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ',level)}{item.Key} = {item.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hAdDZw